# Connection to SQL SERVER on AIX using ruby

Tags: sql-server, ruby, aix

Is there any option to connect to SQL Server using ruby on AIX 7.2? On linux I use tiny_tds gem but installing it requires freetds. There is no official freetds package on AIX that I could use on production in my organisation. Does anyone have experientce to share?

Comment: There are gems that you might be able to get working to use this, but depending on the version of "sql server" you might find that you need to use an old version of ruby, as `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` works with only 2012 and higher.  I unfortunately had to access a 2008R2 server, which meant that my ruby/rails was limited to too old a version for my comfort

Comment: Re: "There is no official freetds package on AIX", Can you compile freetds from source?

Comment: @JaredBeck the main problem here there is no official recommended by IBM SQL Server tool, I could compile this from source but there is a risk that our system administrators will not accept this. There are very strict rules for some systems.

Comment: @Jad activerecord-sqlserver-adapter isn't only for rails?

Comment: Re: ".. our system administrators .. are very strict .." Maybe they can help? Tell them you need a TDS library installed and see what they say?